# how to get data instantly from clipboard in android

Tags: android, service, background, copy, clipboard

[image: screenshot]I want to get text from clipboard instantly when the user copy some text through any application, now i am able to see the text which i copied early (text copied before installation) , after reinstalling the application only the data is updating now , how to make it  update the text instantly ?

this is my main activity

```
package com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.clipme;

import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.ClipData;
 import android.content.ClipboardManager;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);









    ClipboardManager manager=(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clipData =manager.getPrimaryClip();
    ClipData.Item item=clipData.getItemAt(0);
    String string=item.getText().toString();
    final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(string);





    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

this is my content main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.clipme.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
final ClipboardManager manager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
manager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
    Log.i("AppLog", "changed to:" + manager.getText());
    // or this for the textview:
    // textView.setText(manager.getText());
  }
});
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
val manager = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
manager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener { Log.d("AppLog", manager.text?.toString()) }
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

Comment: Is an event method.
In your case try manager instead of ClipboardManager in my answer. You can add this code above to your "FloatingActionButton fab...". Try it

Comment: Wt du you mran by call set text

Comment: Try to delete the "final" in "final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);"

Comment: refer the screenshot please,,,, see my qustion again

Comment: Search in the docs if there amy solutions. My answer i think is for Android 3.0 but maybe search in docs there is a solution. You need a listener for the clipboard copy